# How to set background-image url without auto prefixed host in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css

Say the `index.html` url is `http://localhost/index.html`.

HTML:

```
<div id='test'></div>

<script>
    var el = document.querySelector('#test');
    el.style.background = 'url("/test.png")';
</script>
```

Output html will be:

```
<div id="test" style="background: url(http://localhost/test.png);"></div>
```

I don't want to have the host prefix `http://localhost`. How to prevent the default behaviour of the browser?

Why this requirement? I'm developing a page editor. I need to send back clean html to the server after the html being edited.

I just want to know if there a elegant way to achieve it. No regex replacement or extra tag attributes solution please.

Comment: It is not in the markup, nor in the styles. What you see is just a console output for debugging purposes. So why bother?

Comment: So what do you want? A URL that starts with `/` is *by definition* interpreted as relative to the server root (to put it in a simplified manner).

Comment: I want to send clean html page back to server to store them.

Comment: @YadSmood There is no domain in the source of the HTML page as long as don't set one in the image source URL or the base href…

Comment: @YadSmood "Output html will be: …" No it will not (at least in most browsers) - this is just what is displayed in the console. Can you confirm that behavior/existence of the domain **after** the page was sotred on the server?

Comment: @feeela OK, Chrome only.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the base tag... in Your case something like

```
<base href="http://localhost" target="_blank">
```

and then in your script use:

```
el.style.backgroundImage = 'url("test.png")';
```

standing //localhost/test.png exists, **and Remember to give right dimensions to the div**!